# JMeter with Windows Authentication?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-authentication, jmeter

I am using JMeter to load test some pages that reside in a SharePoint 2007 Site.  The farm that contains the pages resides in a different domain than the machine running the test, and uses Windows Authenticiation.  The connection to the server is over an unencrypted (non-SSL) connection.  Because of this, I need to pass login credentials to the server.

How do I configure JMeter to login to the server using windows authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jakarta-jmeter-user/200612.mbox/%3C8CD5E35E3589F445A265B95DE325BA5EABCB7D@G3W0067.americas.hpqcorp.net%3E)

Edit based on the reply: [new link](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) 
Scroll down to the **Parameters** section,

- **Username**  The username to authorize.
- **Password**  The password for the user.
- **Domain**    The domain to use for NTLM.
- **Realm** The realm to use for NTLM.

Comment: Well that's odd, I posted that one from the office and not I am at home and still works. Using Safari on Mac (posted originally from Chrome on Windows)

Comment: I'm on Firefox on mac.  I'll try safari.

Comment: Thats weird.  The site must have been down.  Its working now.

Comment: That link refers to an issue using JMeter over SSL. I'm not trying to connect over SSL.

Comment: I meant to show you the section where he sets username and password in the post. check this one: 
http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager

Comment: I tried this and it worked.  One thing to note: jmeter has an HTTP Request and a HTTP Client sampler.  I had to use the HTTP Client sampler to get this to work.

Answer (score 6):

make sure to use  http sampler=JAVA

Comment: Choosing Java as the HTTP Request implementation did the trick for me; neither HttpClient3.1 nor HttpClient4 worked (both returned 401 errors). I did not need to use an HTTP Authorization Manager at all, presumably because it's utilizing my own domain credentials automatically (as my Windows PC is connected to the domain).

Answer (score 3):

Add HTTP Authorization Manager to the Thread Group.

Using [domain]username[@realm] as your Windows login example.

BASE URL: [yourdomainurl]

USERNAME: [domain\username] <- UPPERCASE ONLY

PASSOWORD: [password]

This work for my case.