# Cannot get JMeter to authenticate against site during recording

Tags: proxy, jmeter, ntlm, intranet

I am new to Jmeter and have the following problem. It has wasted a couple of days for me so far and I really hope someone can help:

When I go to record the login page of the website (IIS hosted, Windoes Authentication) I ultimately receive a 401 unauthorized. The login popup shows again after details have been entered. These same details function correctly when browsing to the site without the use of Jmeter.

Situation:
Intranet Proxy > JMeter Proxy > Site

I have started JMeter with the Intranet Proxy details:

> jmeter -H  -P 8080 -u  -a  -N localhost

I have created a HTTP Proxy Server in the WorkBench within JMeter

> HTTP Sampler Settings = HttpClient 3.1  / Redirect / Follow and Keep Alive

I have added a HTTP Authorization Manager to the Thread Group providing my details

I have uncommented httpclient.parameters.file=httpclient.parameters in the jmeter.properties file

I have uncommented http.proxyDomain=NTLM domain, if required by HTTPClient sampler in the same file

I have uncommented http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true in the httpclient.parameters file

I believe the NTLM credentials are getting lost somewhere along the way but I do not know where to go at this point.

Let me know if any other information would be of use.

Thanks in advance,
Eoin.

Answer (score 2):

If you are behind a proxy which requires authentication, ensure you set this:

```
  -H PROXY_HOST -P PROXY_PORT -u PROXY_USERNAME -a PROXY_PASSWORD -N localhost
```

Second check your configuration of JMeter Proxy [JMETER PROXY SETUP STEP BY STEP](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Finally if you have NTLM, then it's not sure it can work at least not sure during recording, it also depends on your version of NTLM, see this:

- http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/JMeter-NTLM-authentication-td514319.html

See this:

- [JMeter with Windows Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793649/jmeter-with-windows-authentication)

Finally try asking this question on jmeter user mailing list, once you don't get answer, 
I suggest you put JMeter in DEBUG mode (jmeter.properties) and attach your logs to a BugZilla issue you will open on this (I will look at it as soon as possible).

Comment: Thank you for the responce. Sadly I have followed those links and the information contained within them to no avail.

Comment: Is your site using form authentication or basic one ? You should really go on user mailing list then open a bugzilla with log file, we could help you more efficiently

Answer (score 2):

Works for me in Firefox 40 and IIS with Kerberos authentication if I set `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` -> `HTTP Sampler settings` -> `Type` = `Java`. Need to type the authentication in multiple times, then when I cancel out Firefox is authenticated and I can record the site no problem.